# UIViewController is in wrong orientation when performing navigation controller pop animation

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I am using the new iOS8 viewWillTransitionToSize in my view controller like so:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
      [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [weakSelf handleOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation];

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

    }];
}
```

I am handling rotation changes in the transition block. This works fine.

But if I push another controller on. Rotate the device. Then navigate back using the swipe from the left of the screen pop gesture (interactivePopGestureRecognizer). The view is in the wrong orientation until the pop gesture is complete. If I just pop the controller using a button, the view is in the correct orientation. Also if I move the handle orientation into the completion block, this also works. But on normal rotation there is now no animation.

Here is a link to an example project

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Fq1pK7MmAzWm5TUGRuX0R3Nlk

Steps:

- Select an iOS 8 device
- Push to the second view controller using the button
- Rotate the device
- Navigate back using the swipe gesture

The view will be orientated wrong.

Anyone encountered this problem before? It seems like a bug.

Comment: Any fix on this? Have a similar problem

Comment: I'm also having this issue, have you been able to find a workaround? As a last resort I'd just disable the interactivePopGestureRecognizer so you can only go back through the back button, not ideal at all though.